# Hide row in Crystal Reports Crosstab

Tags: crystal-reports

Is it possible to hide a row in a crystal reports crosstab?

I have two rows that are only used to calculate a third row and I would like to hide them so only the result is visible to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly. I recommend grouping by a custom formula.

For example, let's say you have a crosstab that is grouped by **StoreName**.  **StoreName** has values groups "A", "B", and "C".  You want to combine "B" and "C".

1. Make a new formula field.  Call it **StoreName_Combined**. In your new formula, enter:
   `If {StoreName}="B" or {StoreName}="C" then "B+C" else {StoreName}`
2. In your crosstab, use **StoreName_Combined** instead of **StoreName**.

#### Edit

If you look around a little, you may also think about using **Cross-Tab Expert->Group Options->Options->Use a Formula as a Group Name**, but I couldn't get it to work. The rows stay separate, they just have the same name, which doesn't really help.

Answer (score 4):

I have similar problem. I want to display only rows that have specific values and ignore all others.
Here was my solution:
Open Cross-Tab Expert. In Cross-Tab under Rows select your row which should be conditional suppressed. Then select Group Options. This will open Cross-Tab Group Options dialog. Go to Specified Order and add filter. In this case, rows that match your criteria will be displayed in your cross-table all other rows will be placed in one row "Others". Then select tab Others and check Discard all others.