# Crystal Reports 2013 - to hide/delete row (subitem)

Tags: crystal-reports

On the graph we can see the main items like "Cash and Liquid Assets", "Loan Portfolio", "Securities" and etc. Each of the main items has sub-items, showing what the item consist of.  It looks like :

1. Cash and Liquid Assets  (Item )

   - Cash (subitem)
   - Precious Metals (subitem)
   - Nostro accounts (subitem)
2. Loan Portfolio (item)

   - Individual (subitem)
   - SME (subitem)
   - Micro (subitem)
3. Securities (item)

   - Securities (subitem)

Could you please advice, if the Item contains only one sub-item (as in 3.Securities), not to show sub-item in the graph as they indicate the same amount. I am able to blanc the sub-item , but not to remove the row. This, in turn, make the graph look weird. If it is not possible to remove the sub-item row, please advice how to minimize the row's height .

Comment: Can you show picture

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the link of the picture is below.

Comment: We are complicating the issue....@sanan already hide the rows now he want to supress...for that you can right click the row and select `hide blank rows`...let me know what is the status...actually tried really hard manipulating the cross tab

Comment: i didnt find anything useful ... maybe to add rows (items) and show the sum manually for each group of subitems ?!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: this does not apply, i did not understand it was about a crosstab. I did not delete the answer to preserve the comments below.

I supose you have a group with details. So, "3. Securities" shows up in group header and "Securities" shows up in detail section.

If so, then, you may put a formula to hide the detail section.

1. Create a summary field to count the details per group.
2. Right click the details section and choose "section expert".
3. Find the "Suppress (no drill-down)" check box on the right pane.
4. Click its formula button.
5. If the counter is 1, return true, else return false.

Comment: Dear heringer, Thank you for your reply. Your answer may be a choise. But could you please give me a hint how to write a formula to create formula to count details (sub-item) for a item. (and please take into consideration that we are using cross-tab)

Comment: If i am correct the issue is with graph...this solution is to manipulate details....

Comment: The link of the picture-http://myexcelworld.ucoz.com/Crystal_Reports_2013-hide_subitems.jpg

Comment: May you post a screenshot of the design too?

Comment: Here it is - http://myexcelworld.ucoz.com/Crystal_Reports_2013-hide_subitems_design.jpg

Comment: You are using a crosstab. I think that's Siva's point. So, my answer does not apply, sorry. I think the only way would be change the data source or use the selection expert. Here are some discussions i found: [1] https://scn.sap.com/thread/1407469, [2] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966314/hide-row-in-crystal-reports-crosstab

Comment: i didnt find anything useful ... maybe to add rows (items) and show the sum manually for each group of subitems ?!